# is it possible to increase the ram in google colab with another way?

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I run this code in google colab

```
n = 100000000
i = []
while True:
  i.append(n * 10**66)
```

it happens to me all the time. My data is huge. After hitting 12.72 GB RAM, but I don't immediately get to the crash prompt and the option to increase my RAM.

I have just this Your session crashed after using all available RAM. View runtime logs

What is the solution ? Is there another way ?

Comment: You either need to upgrade to Colab Pro or if your computer itself has more RAM than the VM for Colab, you can connect to your local runtime instead.

Comment: Thanks for informations, you work with Colab pro ? how can I connect to my local runtime ?

Comment: Colab Pro will give you about twice as much memory as you have now. If that’s enough, and you’re willing to pay $10 per month, that’s probably the easiest way. If instead you want to use a local runtime, you can hit the down arrow next to “Connect” in the top right, and choose “Connect to local runtime”

Comment: No problem. If that answer helped you, could you click the check next to the answer below to accept it?

Answer (score 8):

You either need to upgrade to Colab Pro or if your computer itself has more RAM than the VM for Colab, you can connect to your local runtime instead.

Colab Pro will give you about twice as much memory as you have now. If that’s enough, and you’re willing to pay $10 per month, that’s probably the easiest way.

If instead you want to use a local runtime, you can hit the down arrow next to “Connect” in the top right, and choose “Connect to local runtime

Comment: Unfortunately Colab Pro is available only in US/Canada region. And working with local runtime with use of local files is terrible experience.

Answer (score 1):

The policy was changed. However, currently, this workaround works for me:
Open and copy [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1G5FWIEAhu0HJ3Z9jECALH6chAMg11dLy#scrollTo=YOckP_sYQcda) to your drive. Check if you already have 25gb RAM by hovering over the RAM indicator on the top right (this was the case for me). If not, follow the instructions in the colab notebook.

Source: [Github](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/253)

Comment: Working for CPU sessions but not working for GPU sessions, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

as you said 12GB
this needs a large RAM,

if you need a **small increase** you can use colab pro

If you need a **large increase** and using a deep learning framework my advice you should use :

1- the university computer (ACADEMIC & RESEARCH COMPUTING)

 **2- using a platform like AWS, GCP, etc**  3- you may use your very professional computer using GPU (I didn't recommend this)

Answer (score 0):

To double the RAM size of Google Colab use this Notebook, it gives a 25GB RAM! Note: set Runtime type to "None" to double RAM, then change it again to GPU or TPU.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/155S_bb3viIoL0wAwkIyr1r8XQu4ARwA9?usp=sharing