# Is "increase your ram in google colab" still available?

Tags: dataset, ram, google-colaboratory

My dataset is huge, so after running a cell , the session crashed saying using all available ram, and it shows see runtime logs not any increase your ram option, is it still available or closed by google colab? if it is what can I do to work on this huge dataset? Can I add addional 4 GB ram in my laptop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to increase the ram in google colab with another way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745386/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-ram-in-google-colab-with-another-way)

Comment: No I have tried, The option is off now, I have to use google colab pro. Thanks